# How to display interaction element with order way of list one in Kotlin

Tags: list, kotlin

I have two lists and I want to return a result in the following way:

- the result should contain elements that are in list one and list two
- output should be same order as per first list

Input :

```kotlin
val first = listOf(1, 2, 3, 4, 5,7,9,15,11)
val second = listOf(2, 15 , 4,3, 11)
```

Output:

```kotlin
val output = listOf(2,3,4,15,11)
```

Please help me to learn how to get common values in both lists in order of list `first` in Kotlin.

Comment: Don't you mean output should be (2, 3, 4, 15, 11) ?

Comment: yes i want to output like this i have updated it

Answer (score 1):

You can do

```
val output = first.filter { second.contains(it) }
```

Comment: this logic not working because  we have a list of object-type data when i try to compare it it contains list A which is always coming false

Comment: How would you check that two objects be equal? If they are equal when for example an `id` is equal you could do something like `val output = first.filter { second.any { e -> it.id == e.id }}`

Comment: can you please help me { e -> it.id == e.id }}. in this which one a id and which ne b id ?

Comment: `e` from second and `it` from first, maybe it's clearer if you write it like: `output = first.filter { a -> second.any { b -> a.id == b.id }}`

Comment: i am close to it but unable to access b id my data class is  like this below
A Mode Class - class Model(open val localId: Long = 0,  open val createdAt: DateTime) 
B Model Class - clas NewModel(val type: Boolean, val model: Model)

Comment: @MARSH how about: `output = first.filter { a -> second.any { b -> a.localId == b.model.localId }}`

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is the [intersection](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/intersect.html) of the two lists:

```
val output = first.intersect(second)
```

As pointed out by @Ivo the result is a `Set` which can be turned into a list with `output.toList()`. However, since the result is a set, it contains no duplicates, e.g. if `first` is `listOf(1,2,3,1,2,3)` and `second` is `listOf(2,4,2,4)`, the result will be equal to `setOf(2)`.

If this is not acceptable, the solution of @Ivo should be used instead.

Comment: Thanks for helping me let me try i will update you

Comment: This does remove duplicates though because it returns a set. No idea if it's okay in this situation but it's something that needs to be considered. For example if list1 is (1,2,3,1,2,3) and list2 is (2,4,2,4) then intersect only returns (2) and not (2,2)

Comment: Good catch @Ivo, I added that to my answer.

Comment: @Karsten Gabriel thanks for helping i am very close to it my  model class is something like this so its not show data intersected data  A Mode Class - class Model(open val localId: Long = 0,  open val createdAt: DateTime) 
B Model Class - clas NewModel(val type: Boolean, val model: Model)

Comment: @MARSH You should definitely alter your question according to any further requirements that are important for a solution of your precise problem. You should keep the question as simple as possible, but not omit important details (like the fact that you have lists of elements without a proper `equals`, and not lists of `Int`). It does not make any sense to discuss these details in the comments.

Comment: @KarstenGabriel yes sorry i am going to updated it ,